# How is `SIGSEGV` an example of "signals related to the current state of the process be delivered before other signals"?

Tags: linux, signals, segmentation-fault

APUE says

> **What  happens  if  more than  one  signal  is  ready  to  be  delivered  to  a  process?**
>   POSIX.1  does  not  specify  the  order  in  which  the  signals  are delivered  to  the  process.
>   The  Rationale  for  POSIX.1  does  suggest,  however, that  signals  related  to  the  current
>   state of the process be delivered before other signals. (**SIGSEGV is one such signal.**)

How is `SIGSEGV` an example of "signals related  to  the  current
state of the process be delivered before other signals"?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SEGV` is usually delivered when the state of a process is *corrupt* (memory is not mapped where it should be or is mapped with different permissions than expected, the program logic is trying to access memory that it shouldn't be accessing, etc).

In that case, it helps to dump core and die as soon as possible so that subsequent changes don't mess up everything further and render any post-mortem debugging futile.

Comment: Thanks. The question is how SIGSEGV is an example of "What  happens  if  more than  one  signal  is  ready  to  be  delivered  to  a  process?"

Comment: @Tim I think you misquoted your own question.

Comment: Well you could just try it. Run `sh -c 'echo $$; read f'` in a terminal, stop it with `^Z`, attach to it with `strace -p <echoed pid>`, and then from another window run `kill -HUP <pid>; kill -INT <pid>; kill -SEGV <pid>; kill -CONT <pid>` and see which of `INT`, `HUP` or `SEGV` will get it first. Does this make it an example?

Comment: @Tim. In case it isn't clear, `SEGV` will always be delivered before `HUP`, `INT` or `WINCH`, if all of them are pending. This is an example of ""signals related to the current state of the process (`SEGV`, `BUS`, `ILL`) be delivered before other signals (`USR1`, `WINCH`, `INT`, etc)"

Comment: Thanks. What are the reason and purpose that SEGV will always be delivered before HUP, INT or WINCH?